# Ligatures not showing in evince

Tags: fonts, latex

When compiling a latex document, the ligatures (the joined "fi" for example) don't show when looking at the pdf file in evince.

After looking around, I found the answer, but I will post it below for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in font-config

Simply remove the fonts-texgyre package

```
sudo apt-get remove fonts-texgyre
```

(source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tex-gyre/+bug/1317599)